# Ant 1.8.4 does not work in SpringToolSuite 3.2.0. Crashes with SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, spring-tool-suite

I am using SpringToolSuite 3.2.0 which based on Eclipse 4.2.0. When I perform ALT+SHIFT+X+Q which means "Build with Ant", console view just freezes and in error log error appears:

```
Error logged from ANT UI
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
...
at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.launchConfigurations.RemoteAntBuildListeners$ServerConnection.run(RemoteAntBuildLIstener.java:91)
```

Session Data:

```
eclipse.buildId=3.2.0.201303060835-RELEASE-e43
java.version=1.6.0_31
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Command-line arguments: -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just perform right click on my `build.xml` -> `Run As` -> `External Tools Configuration` -> `JRE` tab on my file configuration. Then choose `Run in the same JRE as the workspace`. It was on `Separate JRE`. After switching to `Run in the same JRE as the workspace` everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with your eclipse and buildpath of your projects. Check to see if you can fix it. If not, as suggested in [eclipse forum](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351937), reinstall eclipse and import the projects again

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I fix it another way, without reinstalling. Just perform right click on my build.xml -> `Run As` -> `External Tools Configuration` -> `JRE` tab on my file configuration. Then choose "Run in the same JRE as the workspace". It was on "Separate JRE". After switching to "Same JRE as the workspace" everything is ok.